# Query by date string in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a string field in a collection which stores date in this format `3 Mar 2022`.
Is there anyway to apply `$gt` and `$lt` operators on this in the query? Or is there any other way to query this field?
I am using nodejs/mongoose for querying.
Schema sample

```
export const SampleSchema = new EntitySchema(
    {
        startValidity: { type: String },
        endValidity: { type: String },
    },
    { collection: 'Sample'},
)
```

Please help.

Comment: You cannot compare dates with the format you have now. Date is ideally stored as `Date` type. In case, date is to be stored as a string type, it needs to be `yyyy-mm-dd` format, or with date components as numbers within the string date. Note that MongoDB has Date Aggregation Operators which can be used to convert date data, for example from string type to Date type. In your case, it requires some "logic" to transform the date string to Date type.

Comment: You can try using `$toDate` operator, it can convert the string date to Date type in your case.

Comment: Another proof why one should **never** store date values as strings. Store proper `Date` objects

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks let me try that.

Comment: @prasad_, According [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) Month or Month abbreviations are not supported, so `3 Mar 2022` actually should not work. However, it seems to work, but exact conditions are not clear.

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([ { $addFields: { transformed_date: { $toDate: "$string_dt" } } } ])`, does transform the `string_dt: "3 Mar 2022"` to `"transformed_date" : ISODate("2022-03-03T00:00:00Z"` (using MongoDB v4.2.8). @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score -2):

if your date field is of type date, then you can query like

```
{ $and: [{ myDateField: { $gte: myDateQuery1} }, { myDateField: { $lte: myDateQuery1} }] }
```

Comment: Thanks but it is a string like this `3 Mar 2022`.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your data structure in MongoDB here